# Trying to display multiple image for my product

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I'm trying to display multiple images for one product but the images won't display and i don't know why can anyone help.

My Models. I have to image field one is used to display and product and if the user wants more detail the other is used to show more images of the product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    stock = models.SmallIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('single',args=[self.id,self.slug])

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.image
```

Views

```
def single(request, id, slug):
    try:
        # products = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug)
        images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product)

        return render(request, "single.html",
                        {'product': product},
                        {'images':images})
    except:
        raise Http404
```

How I tried to display the images on the Html page.

```
{% for img in images %}
    {% if item.featured %}
      <img class="img-responsive"src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ img.image.url }}" height="px" width="px" class="pr-5 mr-5">
      {% endif %}
      {% if not item.featured %}
      <img class="img-responsive"src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ img.image.url }}" height="px" width="px" class="pr-5 mr-5">
      {% endif %} 
  {% endfor %}
```

Settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
```

Comment: Try removing MEDIA_URL, src="{{ img.image.url }}" Do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: @danish_wani no i don't

Comment: Remove MEDIA_URL

Comment: @danish_wani no i already tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Inspect the html and see what is the url of image

Comment: @danish_wani the link isn't appearing all is see is ::before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for img in images %}
{% if img.image %}
  <img class="img-responsive"src="{{ img.image.url }}" height="px" width="px" class="pr-5 mr-5">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: still doesn't display

Comment: @Eman... Are you sure you have static url in settings.py and in url?

Comment: @Eman.. Alright, do you have the image saved in database? Because if it's not saved it won't display.

Comment: @Eman...this should work, I can see you are filtering the ID of Product. Why don't you just move the image to Product model, so it can be easy to call in views, instead of creating a separate Model for that.

Comment: i'm trying to display multiple image for one product

Comment: @Eman.. Add this at the bottom of your urls.py: if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @Eman... I don't understand what you mean, no image display on browser at all? It will be much easier to call the image if you add it up to Product model. So it will be like; images=Product.object.all()... Then use my code for the template, you will get your display image.

Comment: @Eman... Maybe this could help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075143/multiple-images-in-django-form-with-multiupload

Answer (score 0):

Remove {{MEDIA_URL}} from src.

> src="{{ img.image.url }}"